# Getting errors when creating new login message

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress plugin and I want to create a new login error message like this:

[image]

I'm using this code for it:

```
add_filter( 'login_errors', $error );
$error = '<strong>ERROR:</strong> Code was invalid.';
```

However, I'm getting 3 errors.

> Notice: Undefined variable: error in
>   \wp-content\plugins\directory\[cut].php
>   on line 119
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   [cut]plugin.php on line 925
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   [cut]plugin.php on line 943

I have tried to put `$error` above the filter, but that didn't work either.

What is going wrong??

Comment: Can you declare $error = ''; Try this

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: $error don't declare and it using for add_filter function. This's an error.

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn I'm still getting the same errors, and I'm sure I'm doing it wrong. http://pastebin.com/raw/vEZsaa62

Comment: What's plugin you using?

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn I made the plugin myself

Comment: Can you upload your plugin so I can help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read documentation about [add_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) function.

The second parameter is:

> **$function_to_add** (callable) (Required) The callback to be run when the filter is applied.

It should be string with function name. In your case following code should work:

```
function return_custom_error() {
  $error = '<strong>ERROR:</strong> Code was invalid.';
  return $error;
}

add_filter( 'login_errors', 'return_custom_error' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the codex for log_errors hook: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_errors

the second parameter you should pass in is a function:

something like this:

```
add_filter( 'login_errors', function($error) { return $error = '<strong>ERROR:</strong> Code was invalid.';} );
```